# Using autonumber field type as externalId to make an upsert & store values in a Map from soql by external id

Tags: apex, rest-api, externalid

I know that those questions asked a few times here - but I saw that it little old (Greater than 3 years) and\or it doesn't have the "best answer" so I hope something changed about it.

1) Is there a way to upsert by externalId autonumber field type? (without copying that field to new field with workflow).

2) Is there a way to store values in a Map from soql query that the key will be externalId - without go through on a list and insert the key,value within the loop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Is there a way to upsert by externalId autonumber field type? (without copying that field to new field with workflow).

In fact, this is very likely something we will **never** be able to do. Doing so would break database expectations (e.g. you insert a value of out sequence, and so later there are duplicate values). It could have a lot of unintended side effects. Salesforce can't control the generation of the auto-number values if it can be influenced by an outside system, thus defeating the purpose of an auto-number field. You would necessarily need to write a trigger to implement this functionality.

> 2) Is there a way to store values in a Map from soql query that the key will be externalId - without go through on a list and insert the key,value within the loop?

No. Again, this is also likely something that will never happen. It's simply too specialized. If you have a specific need, you can write your own utility methods to reuse this, but don't expect Apex to have this kind of built-in support.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox for the detailed answer.